# How to solve error from PHP BATIK? Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart?

Tags: php, highcharts, xampp

I am using XAMPP to host a website. My website contains Highcharts. I am trying to let my server export the chart according to this http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server
When my web calls the PHP BATIK, the troubleshoot tells me this.

> Output: dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart Referenced
>   from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
>   Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libJPEG.dylib in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO